# Use Perl to only print only if the value of column A appears with every different value of Column B

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

So in Perl how can I go through a sample file like so:

```
1 D Z
1 E F
1 G L 
2 D I
2 E L
3 D P
3 G L
```

So here I want to be able to print out only the values that have a value in the first column that appears with every different value of the second column.

The output would look like this:

```
1 D Z
1 E F
1 G L
```

Comment: This explanation of what you need is really confused.

Comment: Ok so if all values in column 1 are present in each value in column 2 then print out the output. For example if I had 3 files D, E, and G and all files had 1 in it then print those values, but how do can I check that. Does that help?

Comment: @BobbyMcMillan: How about explaining why the lines starting with `2` and `3` *aren't* printed?

Comment: The lines starting with 2 and 3 are not printed because those values are not present in all files D, E, G. I only want to print if the values in the first column are present for all the values in the second column. Thus in this case 1 is present in D, E, and G so I would only print out that information.

Comment: 2 is only present in D and E but not G so I would not print that out.

Comment: 3 is present in D and G but not E so I would not print that out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this isn't as easy as it seems. I've read the file into memory so that I can take three passes over it

- Count the number of different values in column 2
- Record each combination of values in column 1 and column 2
- Print those lines in the file whose first column has as many occurrences as there are different values of column 2

This could be improved with more information about the input file, but it works fine as it is and I see no reason to optimise it

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;

my @lines = <>;

my @col2 = uniq map { (split)[1] } @lines;

my %data;
for ( @lines ) {
    my ($c1, $c2) = split;
    $data{$c1}{$c2} = 1;
}

for ( @lines ) {
    my ($c1) = split;
    print if keys %{ $data{$c1} } == @col2;
}
```

#### output

```
1 D Z
1 E F
1 G L
```

Answer (score 0):

> cat test

1 D Z

1 E F

1 G L

2 D I

2 E L

3 D P

3 G L

> perl -a -lne 'unless ( $h{ $F[1] } ) { print }; $h{ $F[1] } = 1; ' test

1 D Z

1 E F

1 G L